# SharePoint Managed Properties (Mappings) - Multiple Site Collections

Tags: sharepoint, search, properties, moss

Have mapped properties for custom fields used in multiple site collections.

The property is also used to display additional information on the search results page if it contains information.

The search results work fine as content from each site collection is returned, but the managed property only contains data for content found on one particular site collection.

When configuring the managed property, there is only one option available to select the custom field I wish to map.

A full crawl has completed since configuring the managed property.  The content from each site collection is being indexed, but the managed properties are only populated with data for content on one site collection.

Are the fields available to select when configuring a managed property from all site collections, or do I need to change a setting somewhere to tell it to look for custom fields in an alternate site collection?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before and it is possible and indeed straightforward, you do not need to set any special settings. Just make sure that the internal names of the fields are the same (or all names are mapped to the managed property) and all lists/sites are set to be included in search results

Comment: Thanks Vladi,

I checked to make sure that columns from each site collection were being crawled, which they were.

The issue was that the internal name was the in the format of an Id and not the column name.  When configuring the mapped property, I needed to search for part of the column Id.

Something must have gone wong when the content types were deployed accross each site collection.

Thanks again.

Comment: Related Blog Post: 

http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/08/metadata-property-mappings-managed.html